# Appropriate designation for a personal email address at yourname.com

Tags: domains, email, personal-website, email-address

Say your name is John Doe, and you own johndoe.com.

What are the best practices for identifying your personal email at that domain?

- john@johndoe.com is redundant
- me@johndoe.com seems a bit juvenile
- info@johndoe.com and webmaster@johndoe.com are too impersonal

Am I missing a more appropriate alternative?

<sub>(I know this is on the fringe, but I'm hoping it's just north of objective--or at least interesting enough to the community to get some good feedback.)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be contact@johndoe.com
Because these tells user both the purpose i.e. 
1. Contact 
2. The person who is being contacted i.e. John over here.
Let me know what you think.

Comment: contact@ would most probably be exposed to a lot of spam emails

Answer (score 2):

Redundant or not, `john@johndoe.com` would probably be the most expected, though it could potentially see your inbox get some spam. As an alternative, I'd go with either `personal@johndoe.com` or possibly even `actual@johndoe.com` because I'm a BSG fan.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with hello@myname.com

Answer (score 0):

i@johndoe.com, with extending to, f.e, mom@, dad@ etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about being impersonal, try using your official title.  `chief@johndoe.com` or even `theboss@johndoe.com`. As an entrepreneur, I've seen too many people pass up an opportunity to get into the hearts of their customers. Your email address should be creative, especially with your name as the domain name.

Get creative with it and use something unique. Expected is boring and is going to flop in today's business world. Whether your marketing yourself or a product, it's boring.